# Seekbar set thumb with secondprogress

Tags: android, slider, progress-bar, seekbar

Refferance [Changing Android SeekBar to draw secondary progress on top of primary progress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618746/changing-android-seekbar-to-draw-secondary-progress-on-top-of-primary-progress)

I want to make a seekbar that has thumb independent from progress or add a thumb to a progressbar so I can work independently with progress/secondaryProgress/thumb.

Ideally I would like to set secondaryProgress via dragging thumb.

I looked trough the source code of SeekBar, AbsSeekBar and ProgressBarr. The code is very ambiguous and a lot of methods can't be overriden.

I'm looking forward to making a draggable thumb that sets scondaryProgress, and on release, the progress starts rising to reach the level of the thumb.

Comment: what exactly  do you want to do in that method?

Comment: I think I have to rewrite this method, not certain.
I want to set my secondprogress when I drag the thumb, instead of setting the real progress.

Comment: what you probably need to do is to create a custom Drawable rhat you pass to setProgressDrawable method

Comment: I see that setProgress method sets the progress and thumb to the specified value, I think I need to override that method.

Comment: btw SeekBar already has the "secondary progress" feature,  doesn't it work for you?

Comment: I want to drag the thumb with secondary progress, but setProgress() sets the progress and thumb.
setSecondaryProgress is not related to the thumb

Comment: so override setSecondaryProgress and call super.setProgress and override setProgress and call super.setSecondaryProgress

Comment: It would set my progress as well, I want my progress to stay still.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://code.google.com/p/regie-eclairage-saint-michel

Use this project that has a vertical seekbar based on the original source code.
It contains source code for VerticalProgressBar, VerticalAbsSeekBar, VerticalSeekbar exactly as the original,just verical.