# WinRT Slider draw secondary progress on top of primary progress?

Tags: winrt-xaml

I want to build custom slider with secondary progress on top of the primary progress chosen by the customer.

something like that in android: [Changing Android SeekBar to draw secondary progress on top of primary progress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618746/changing-android-seekbar-to-draw-secondary-progress-on-top-of-primary-progress)

Thanks

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ProgressBar Height="2" MinHeight="2"
                 Margin="0,-6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Foreground="Silver" IsHitTestVisible="False"
                 Value="65" />
    <Slider Background="Transparent" Value="35" />
</Grid>
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Sort of like the YouTube seek bar, right?

Best of luck!